# ionic phonegap-facebook-plugin iOS build - CompileC build error

Tags: facebook, authentication, ionic-framework, native

The plugin had been working beautifully up until last night. Getting the following errors on iOS only after updating to latest Ionic/Cordova (android is fine).

**Updated to:**
xcode version 7.2.1
ionic version 1.7.14

I have also tested the same app with another mac running previous version of ionic 1.7.13 and cordova 6, and all is good.

After testing with the older version, i built a new mac (fresh wives laptop) with the latest ionic setup and again same error.

Here's the plugin in question https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework

**The following build commands failed:**
    CompileC build/testFresh.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testFresh.build/Objects-normal/i386/FacebookConnectPlugin.o testFresh/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Applications/AMPPS/www/ionic/testFresh/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,testFresh.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,testFresh,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/AMPPS/www/ionic/testFresh/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/AMPPS/www/ionic/testFresh/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Answer (score 5):

After banging my head against a wall for a few days, I found that others were having the same issue though it was labeled as a "cordova 6" problem.

**Original github issue:** 
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1227

Eventually whilst scrolling through known bugs under github for "phonegap-facebook-plugin" i noticed that similar errors had occurred on a previous release, then super Jeduan re-wrote the plugin and released it under the following:

**Plugin fix:**
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

The above appears to be working find under cordova 6, xcode version 7.2.1 and ionic version 1.7.14